# Modifing current object in foreach loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller

When I did($id_paket); going well but when you enter code here enter the database, why only the last input is stored?

> Controller:

```
public function update_penawaran(Request $request,$id)
{
    $harga_satuan = $request->input('harga_satuan');
    foreach ($request->input('harga_satuan') as $key => $hargasatu) {
      DB::table('tbl_pesanan as a')
      ->join('tbl_paket as b', 'a.id_paket', '=', 'b.id_paket')
      ->where('a.id_paket', $id)
      ->update([
          'b.status_paket' => $request->status_paket,
          'harga_satuan' => $harga_satuan[$key]
      ]);
    }
    // dd($harga_satuan);
    return redirect('/pesanan')->with('success','Berhasil Menambahkan Penawaran!');
}
```

> View:

```
@foreach($pesanan as $p)


<tbody>
    <tr id="addRow" >
      <td class="col-xs-3" style="text-align: center;" >  {{$p->kode_bmn}}
      </td>

  <td class="col-xs-3" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->jenis_barang}}
  </td>
  <td class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->kuantitas}}
  </td>
  <td class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->satuan_ukuran}}
  </td>
  <td class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->kode_ruang}}
  </td>
  <td class="col-xs-3">
    <input class="form-control " name="harga_satuan[] " type="text" placeholder="Enter title" />
  </td>
</tr>


</tbody>
  @endforeach
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

id_pesanan (primarykey) id_paket (foreignkey)
How can this problem be resolved?

Comment: because you are updating multiple rows many times, and at last those rows' values will be updated by the last loop.

Comment: how to solve the problem?

Comment: the problem is how do u know which line need to be updated to 
 `$harga_satuan[$key]`

Answer (score 0):

That's my simple solution.

> Controller

Change

```
->where('a.id_paket', $id)
```

Into

```
->where('a.id_paket', $key)
```

> View

Change

```
<input class="form-control " name="harga_satuan[] " type="text" placeholder="Enter title" />
```

Into

```
<input class="form-control " name="harga_satuan[{{ $p->id_paket }}][] " type="text" placeholder="Enter title" />
```